# Share an image on facebook

Tags: android, share

I'm getting crazy for this. I need to share the image screen on facebook.

This is my code for now:

```
if(mLatLngList.isEmpty() && mMyLatLngList.isEmpty() && (mMergedMarkers == false)) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Importa o disegna un percorso", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    Bitmap originalBitmap = screenShot(findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView());

    String pathofBmp = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), originalBitmap,"title", null);
    Uri bmpUri = Uri.parse(pathofBmp);

    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bmpUri);
    shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share"));

private Bitmap screenShot(View view) {
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(),
            view.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    view.draw(canvas);
    return bitmap;
}
```

I edited the post. With this code i can share the screen image on facebook BUT the map is all black! >.<

Comment: It may help people answer your question quicker if you provide the contents of LogCat that shows the error

Comment: ...So where are the Logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should debug the app by putting a `Breakpoint` right to the start of `shareGpx`. This way you will be able to examine which variable is `null`.

Taking screenshots of Maps isn't that easy - You have to implement a certain callback. You can find more information in the official documentation at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.SnapshotReadyCallback

Comment: The image is correctly shared on facebook. In my app i use the GoogleMap but the map is black in the shared image :(. I think because   the map "is not a part" of getRootView()...

Comment: Ok i did it ;) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

`mLatLngList` or `mMyLatLngList` or `mMergedMarkers` might be null , because rest of the code is fine.